# How to fetch a single row from a MySQL DB using MySQLi with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using PHP with MySQli and I want to fetch a single row from the whole SQL DB, which fits in my condition. Just for a note, this is what my current database looks like :

[image: sample database]

I want to get that single row where, eg. `txnid` column's value == `$txnid (a variable)`. I tried to build the SQL Query which would fit my requirements, and here's how it looks like : **`$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'txnid' = " . $txnid;`**. When I raw-run this Query in phpMyAdmin, it works as expected. I just want to know, after I run the Query in PHP, how to fetch that row's data which came in as response from the Query using MySQLi?

This is the code which I am using to run the Query :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$txnid = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `testtable1` WHERE `txnid` = " . $txnid;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo ""; //what should I do here, if I want to echo the 'date' param of the fetched row?
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Did you try `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: `$txnid = $_GET()` What is it?? missing `;` and what u GET?

Comment: Sorry @Ashok I forgot to name the param there - please consider there's a param name inside the braces. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a warning: that code is widely open for SQL injection. Widely as in: you cannot make it less secure than that..... Please have a look at prepared statements!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query to produce a single row of data.

Your method is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements to avoid this. Here are some links you can review:

- [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select

---

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");

$txnid= $_GET['name_of_txnid_input_field'];

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `testtable1` WHERE `txnid` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $txnid);

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['date_field_you_want_to_display'];
```

Comment: the txnid field looks unique. why adding LIMIT?

Answer (score -7):

```
$txnid = $_POST['txnid'];   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE txnid = $txnid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks, is $result the response row?

Comment: Be forewarned this answer would likely open a critical SQL injection vulnerability; a secure answer would leverage parameterized queries and prepared statements.